# Почему не получается редактировать текст в Label?

Tags: java, javafx

Я так понимаю, что должно получиться это:

```
    public static Exercise start() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxml;
    Parent panel1;
    Scene scene;
    Stage WindowExercise;
    fxml = new FXMLLoader (Exercise.class.getResource("Window1(Otgimanie).fxml"));
    WindowExercise=new Stage();
    try{
        panel1 = fxml.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    scene=new Scene(panel1,335,240);// Здесь Локальная переменная panel1 могла быть не инициализирована говорит eclipse

    WindowExercise.setScene(scene);
    WindowExercise.show();
    TextOtgimanie.setText("");
    return (Exercise)(fxml.getController());
}
```

В другом классе:

```
public void exercise(){
    if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный"){  
        Exercise.start();
    }
}
```

Я перенес тело статического метода в exercise, но всё равно то же предупреждение от среды разработки:

```
   public Exercise exercise(){//Данный метод должен возвращать результат типа Exercise
    if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный"){  
        FXMLLoader fxml;
        Parent panel1;
        Scene scene;
        Stage WindowExercise;
        fxml = new FXMLLoader (Exercise.class.getResource("Window1(Otgimanie).fxml"));
        WindowExercise=new Stage();

            try {
                panel1 = fxml.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {}

        scene=new Scene(panel1,335,240);//Локальная переменная panel1 могла быть не инициализирована
        WindowExercise.setScene(scene);
        WindowExercise.show();

        return (Exercise)(fxml.getController());

    }

}
```

Но здесь ошибка. Как её исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявили переменную, но не проинициализировали. Вот и выпадает `NullPointerException`

Нужно сделать как-то так

```
Label TextOtgimanie = new Label();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@FXML   
static Label TextOtgimanie;
```

Раз есть аннотация `@FXML` то подразумевается что это контроллер и привязан к файлу разметки `fxml`. При этом все переменные с такой аннотацией инициализироются автоматически ЕСЛИ они действительно есть в файле `fxml`. Иначе, при обращении к ней будет вылетать `NullPointerException`.

Если же вы не пользуетесь этой структурой, то как сказал **LEQADA**, все инициализируем ручками.

```
Label TextOtgimanie = new Label();
```

**UPD**

Проблема была в том что контроллер так просто не инициализируется. Вот простенький пример:

```
Parent root = new FXMLLoader(URLToFXMLFile).load();
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 200));
stage.showAndWait();
```

Также если fxml где-то глубоко в теле проекта то URL можно получить так:

```
getClass().getResource("source/fxml/fxml.fxml"));
```

**UPD 2**
Чтобы провести первоначальную настройку в контроллере, нужно реализовать в нем интерфейс `Initializible`:

```
public class Exercise implements Initializable{
}
```

после чего система попросит вас реализовать необходимый в нем метод:

```
public class Exercise implements Initializable{

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
      TextOtgimanie.setText("");
   }

}
```

И первичную настройку делать лучше именно так! Так как на момент вызова этого метода все элементы интерфейса с аннотацией `@FXML` будут уже проинициализированы.

**UPD 3**
Вот так мы сможем получить объект класса:

```
public static Exercise start() {
    FXMLLoader fxml;
    Parent panel1;
    Scene scene;
    Stage WindowExercise;
    fxml = new FXMLLoader (Exercise.class.getResource("Window1(Otgimanie).fxml"));
    WindowExercise=new Stage();
    try {
        panel1 = fxml.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    scene=new Scene(panel1,335,240);
    WindowExercise.setScene(scene);
    WindowExercise.show();
    TextOtgimanie.setText("");//При добавлении этой строчки выдает ошибку
    return (Exercise)(fxml.getController());
}
```

И в итоге у нас будет рабочий объект Exercise, через который мы сможем редактировать Label.

Comment: Да, TextOtgimanie есть в файле fxml. Я это проверял несколько раз, но все равно ошибка выдается

Comment: Можете показать кусок этого файла? Также: правильно ли указано имя? (Он ошибки не выдаст при этом)

Comment: <Label fx:id="TextOtgimanie" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="">
         <font>
            <Font size="19.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>

Comment: Ой, не там! Ошибка была в инициализации. Надо не контроллер инициализировать а загружать fxml. В основном ответе сейчас напишу.

Comment: Как загрузить fxml?

Comment: Вторая половина моего ответа, я туда дописал.

Comment: А разве я этого не сделал?panel1=FXMLLoader.load(Exercise.class.getResource("Window1(Otgimanie).fxml"));

Comment: Понял, но в любом случае зря вы так извернулись, тк когда fxml загружается, создается НОВЫЙ экземпляр контроллера, уже с проинициализированными переменными. А тот, что вы создали так и останется бесхозным.

Comment: Как вариант сделать этот метод статичным. А чтобы он возвращал объект контроллера у FXMLLoader есть .getController();. (А это кстати идея, надо запомнить)

Comment: А разве он не статичный?public static void start() {

Comment: Ну тогда эта строка не нужна Exercise exercise=new Exercise();. Нужно только Exercise.start();. Именно из класса а не объекта вызывать.

Comment: Попробовал, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку

Comment: static Label TextOtgimanie; - статик уберите.

Comment: Тогда точно не будет работать, ведь метод статичный, а из статичного метода нельзя обращаться к не статичным объектам

Comment: TextOtgimanie - элемент интерфейса, который должен быть уникален для КАЖДОГО вновь открытого окна. Загрузчик fxml не проинициализирует его, если он статичный. А значение по умолчанию можно задать в методе inicialize(). Его расширяет интерфейс Inicializable. Или вобще в самой fxml

Comment: Я новичок, не могли бы поподробнее рассказать , как это сделать?

Comment: Или где почитать про это?

Comment: Добавил в конце своего ответа, ибо текст крупноват.

Comment: Это прекрасно работает, на мне нужно часто менять значение TextOtgimanie. Как это делать, не подскажите?

Comment: Тогда вынести тело метода start() наружу и сделать отдельную переменную для FXMLLoader. После вызова метода .load(), у него можно вызвать .getController(), который вернет нам объект контроллера, и с ним уже можно работать так, как вам надо.

Comment: Простите, я чувствую себя идиотом, но прошу поподробнее объяснить, как это сделать. Я вам очень благодарен, за всю помощь

Comment: Или опять же, где можно про это почитать? Не подскажите?

Comment: Я привел конкретный код метода start(). А где прочитать, не скажу. Я сам учился методом тыка по разрозненным статьям.

Comment: Посмотрите, я обновил вопрос. Кое-что не получается

Comment: Не знайте как это исправить?

Comment: TextOtgimanie.setText(""); Я же говорил, его нельзя делать статическим, и вызывать из статического метода тоже нельзя! Читаем UPD 2 !

Comment: Хорошо, но как всё равно среда разработки ругается на                        try{
        panel1 = fxml.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    scene=new Scene(panel1,335,240);                       И говорит, что локальная переменная panel1 могла быть не инициализирована

Comment: Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: У метода getResource есть ограничение, его можно вызвать только из конкретного объекта. Тоесть от статического метода start вобще нужно отказаться! Все тело метода переносите в то место где вы хотели вывести это окно, за пределы этого класса. В вашем примере это метод exercise();

Comment: Ещё одна ошибка после этого добавилась

Comment: А каков текст ошибки?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33412/discussion-on-answer-by-rihard-brugekhaim-----).

Comment: Среда разработки говорит, что   scene=new Scene(panel1,335,240);//Локальная переменная panel1 могла быть не инициализирована

Comment: Scene scene = null; Так напиши.